# modelbinder with dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's what I'm trying to do :

I have an entity **Task** with a TaskName property and a **TaskPriority** property.

Now, in the html I have :

```
<td><%=Html.TextBox("Task.TaskName") %></td>
<td><%=Html.DropDownList("Task.TaskPriority",new SelectList(ViewData.Model.TaskPriorities,"ID","PriorityName")) %></td>
```

The Controller action is like this :

```
public ActionResult Create(Task task){
    //task.TaskName has the correct value
    //task.TaskPriority is null - how should the html look so this would work ?
}
```

**EDIT**
In the example bellow (from Schotime) :

```
public class Task
{
    public int name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; } // what if the type of the property were Dropdown ?
       // in the example I gave the Task has a property of type: TaskPriority.
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that TaskPriority is a class?? if so then you would need to specify Task.TaskPriority.PropertyName   for the dropdownlist name.

Comment: That works indeed :) . Please edit your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work.

Three classes:

```
    public class Container
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Dropdown> drops { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dropdown
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public int name { get; set; }
        public TaskPriority priority { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskPriority
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Tasks()
    {
        List<dropdown> ds = new List<Dropdown>();
        ds.Add(new Dropdown() { id = 1, value = "first" });
        ds.Add(new Dropdown() { id = 2, value = "second" });

        ViewData.Model = new Container() { name = "name", drops = ds };

        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Tasks(Task drops)
    {
        //drops return values for both name and value
        return View();
    }
```

View: Strongly typed `Viewpage<Container>`

```
<%= Html.BeginForm() %>
<%= Html.TextBox("drops.name") %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("drops.priority.value",new SelectList(ViewData.Model.drops,"id","value")) %>
<%= Html.SubmitButton() %>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

When i debugged it worked as expected.
Not sure what you are doing wrong if you have something similar to this.
Cheers.